# sqlite creating new rows based on column conditions

Tags: sql, sqlite, conditional-statements, database-schema

I receive a database like this:

```
Product   Condition1   Condition2   Condition 3
Computer  1            2           
Car       1            2            3
```

What they want from me is to export a database in this form:

```
Product   Condition
Computer  1
Computer  2
Car       1
Car       2
Car       3
```

It's a lot of data, would not make any sense to fix stuff manually. Do you have any idea how would i get dynamic solution for this. I would highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT product, condition1 FROM table_name
UNION SELECT product, condition2 FROM table_name
UNION SELECT product, condition3 FROM table_name
UNION ORDER BY product
```

Comment: You need to remove the final UNION before the ORDER BY